How to get properties of real IBM Quantum Computer in Qiskit SDK 1.0?
I have the code below:
def load_IBMQ(channel,token):
    service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel=channel, token=token)
    #if len(IBMQ.stored_account()) == 0:
      #  IBMQ.save_account(token)
       # IBMQ.load_account()
    #elif IBMQ.active_account() == None:
     #   IBMQ.load_account()
    provider = service.backends(simulator=False, operational=True)#least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)#IBMQ.get_provider(hub=hub, group=group, project=project)
    print("provider", provider)
    return provider
def get_device_info(channel,token,device_name,fields,datetime):
    dirname = './devices/%s'%datetime.date()
    filename = '%s/%s.pckl'%(dirname,device_name)
    _device_info = read_dict(filename=filename)
    if len(_device_info)==0:
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            os.makedirs(dirname)
        else:
            subprocess.run(['rm','-r',dirname])
            os.makedirs(dirname)
        provider = load_IBMQ(channel=channel,token=token)
        for x in provider:

            if 'qasm' not in str(x):
                device =x#get_backend(str(x))
                properties = device.properties(datetime=datetime)
                print("....properties....", properties)


                num_qubits = device.configuration().n_qubits#len(properties.qubits)
                print('Download device_info for %d-qubit %s'%(num_qubits,x))
                coupling_map = CouplingMap(device.configuration().coupling_map)
                noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(device)
                basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates
                _device_info = {'properties':properties,#device.configuration(),
                'coupling_map':coupling_map,
                'noise_model':noise_model,
                'basis_gates':basis_gates}
                pickle.dump(_device_info, open('%s/%s.pckl'%(dirname,str(x)),'wb'))
            print('-'*50)
        _device_info = read_dict(filename=filename)
    device_info = {}
    for field in fields:


        if field=='device':
            provider = load_IBMQ(channel=channel,token=token)
            #print(device_name)

            device = device_name#provider.get_backend(device_name)
            device_info[field] = device
        else:
            device_info[field] = _device_info[field]
    print("get_device_info end")
    return device_info

I get error
device_info[field] = _device_info[field]
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'properties'

How I get properties of real IBM quantum computer like ibm_osaka or others quantum computer in Qiskit SDK 1.0

Once you have got the list of backends from a service as in your load_IBMQ function above (also see get-backend-information in qiskit docs), you can access the properties of each backend through its attributes (see IBMBackend in qiskit docs) i.e.,
print(backend.coupling_map)

output:
[[0, 1], [0, 14], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 3], [4, 15], ...

or through the backend configuration as follows
configuration = backend.configuration()
print(configuration.coupling_map)

output:
[[0, 1], [0, 14], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 3], [4, 15], ...

